# If two functions are different at one point, but equal at the rest, one must be discontinous

Tags: real-analysis

I need to prove the statement given below, I hope you can give me some feedback.

**Claim**: If two functions $f,g : \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ are different at a point, but equal to each other at all other points, can both functions be continous at every point?

**Proof**: If both functions are continous and equal at every point in the given domain, except for $x = a$, we define a new function $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$ such that:

$$\left\{\begin{matrix}
\ h(x) = 0, x\neq 0
\\ h(x) = c, x = a, c \in \mathbb{R} \setminus\{0\}
\end{matrix}\right.$$

If $h(x)$ isn't continous, then either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ isn't continous, as we have defined $h(x)$ to be a difference between two continous functions.

Using epsilon - delta, we check continuity at $x=a$:

$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists\delta>0|\forall x \in \mathbb{R}, |x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |h(x)-h(a)|<\epsilon$

Letting $\delta = \epsilon/2$, we get that:

$|x-a|<\epsilon/2 \Rightarrow |h(x)-h(a)|=c$

But this doesn't implicate that epsilon is less than $|h(x)-h(a)|$. Acutally, no matter how small delta we choose, we can't get $|h(x)-h(a)|<c$. And since c is a real non zero number, we can't pick any arbitrary epsilon greater than zero such that this implication works out. Therefore, our function $h(x)$ isn't continous.

**Conclusion** Either $f(x)$ or $g(x)$ must be discontinous at that point, hence, one of them can't be continous on their whole domain respectively.

$\blacksquare$

I think my proof isn't that clear when I'm using my epsilon - delta, but I hope I can get some tips on how to improve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your proof is indeed not *clear when using epsilon*.

The limit definition starts with "for every epsilon". To find the counterexample you are looking for you need just one epsilon, and you do seem to know what it is. So you argue

> Let $\epsilon = c/2$ ...

and show that no $\delta$ will work.

Comment: Thank you, I see where this is going now :)